# Any way to remove the BOM part when a NSData has many BOM inside it?(Objective-c)

Tags: encoding, nsdata, byte-order-mark

Normally if the file contains a BOM at the beginning of a file or a data, it is useful to identify what encoding the data is.

But if you use NSData's `dataUsingEncoding` method, it would add a BOM if the encoding requires one.So if you use this method several time and append these data together as a output data and write it to file, then the file will contains several BOM.And the BOMs except the first one will be in the data part.

For example:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
[data appendData:[@"abc" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:[@"123" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
[data appendData:[@"qwe" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
```

Then the str would be : abc\ufeff123\ufeffqwe (Although if you NSLog it ,it would says abc123qwe, I think this is because of NSLog has done with the output).

But I want the str to be exactly abc123qwe, is there any elegant way to eliminate these BOM? Or can I just  check through the string and manually remove all the BOM?

Comment: (Not familiar with the API) - Shouldn't you append all of the data and then encode it once, rather than encoding each part in turn and appending them?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Maybe I should encoding it once to work through this issue, but I still think it should be OK I use it this way

Comment: Consider what would happen if you used *different* encodings for each piece of data. That "should work" under your assumption, but how would the receiver interpret the data?

Comment: I agree with you, the BOM is necessary to identify the encoding. But it is inconvenient when you use the API like my example.So I asked this question for some solution to remove some unnecessary BOM.